# Varnish Regular Expression for get variable array

Tags: regex, varnish-vcl

I'm looking to extract get variable values from URLs inside of varnish.  The get variable in question is named "source" and may or may not be an array.  I would like to take the value(s) of source and comma separate them.  Putting the URLs through my desired regex would yield the following:

- t.com/?source=**1**

  - 1
- t.com/?a=1&source=**1**

  - 1
- t.com/?source[]=**1**

  - 1
- t.com/?source[]=**1**&source[]=**2**

  - 1,2
- t.com/?a=1&source[]=**1**&source[]=**2**

  - 1,2
- t.com/?a=1&source[]=**1**&source[]=**2**&source[]=**3**

  - 1,2,3

I have created the regex that matches each of those cases appropriately, though I have little experience with capture groups for the purpose of replacement.  Here is what I have constructed:

```
((\?|\&)source(\[])?=(?P<sources>[^&]+))+
```

Visualization: https://www.debuggex.com/i/_2ib6j-6VKTWE_vV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since varnish has really limited functionalities (no array manipulation, loops, ...), a way to do this is to apply two regexes:

1. The first will capture the `source` values and replace it with comma separated values

   use `.*?[&?]source(?:\[\])?=([^&=\n]+)` and replace with `$1,` => [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yA2fT3/5)
2. The second will remove the trailing comma

   use `,$` and replace with an empty string => [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/iR3fY5/2)

Comment: That regex looks great but would yield a false positive for get variables that end with source (e.g. utm_source=test).  To resolve that issue, I've updated the regex [as follows](http://regex101.com/r/yA2fT3/3): `.*?(?:\?|&)source(?:\[\])?=([^&=\n]+)`